# Alternate proof that the event of convergence of series is in tail sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I am trying to show that the event that a series of independent random variables converge is in the tail sigma-algebra. That is,
\begin{equation}
\{ \omega: \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_{k}({\omega}) < \infty \} \in \mathcal{G}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{G}_{n},
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{G}_{n}=\sigma(X_{n},X_{n+1}, \dots)$. I know how to do it using the fact that the series converges if and only if the tail sum converges but I tried to do it by the following method: 
\begin{equation}
\{ \omega: \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_{k}({\omega}) < \infty \}=\bigcap_{a=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m \geq n}\{\omega :|\sum_{m}^{\infty}X_{m}(\omega)| < \frac{1}{a}\}
\end{equation}
The second intersection is clearly in $\mathcal{G}_{n}$ but I am not able to show the whole term is in $\mathcal{G}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

$$\left\{\omega : \sum_{k\ge 0} X_k(\omega)<\infty\right\}=\bigcap_{a\ge 1} \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \bigcap_{m\ge n} \left\{\omega : \sum_{k\ge m} X_k(\omega)<1/a\right\}$$

Let's fix $s$. You want to prove that your event is in $\mathcal{G}_s$. Notice that you get exactly the same event if you start the second union from $s$:

$$\left\{\omega : \sum_{k\ge 0} X_k(\omega)<\infty\right\}=\bigcap_{a\ge 1} \bigcup_{n\ge s} \bigcap_{m\ge n} \left\{\omega : \sum_{k\ge m} X_k(\omega)<1/a\right\}$$

Now the RHS is in $\mathcal{G}_s$, and so is the LHS (and this for all $s$).